# How to render an image in sveltepress markdown?

Tags: svelte

I am using [sveltepress](https://sveltepress.site/) to create a docs site, and in this app, you get access to writing markdown which will be rendered in the svelte framework.

However, I'm having a hard time rendering an image.

Typically, in markdwon, you show an image as such:

```markdown
![image](./path/to/image.png)
```

However, I can't see to figure out:

1. Where to place the image
2. What path to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images will go into the `/static` directory.

Any image you place in there is available as root `/`

Example

`/static/logo.png`

can then be used in the .md file as

`![image](/logo.png)`